# Why isn't my PHPUnit mock of the Predis Client matching my expectations?

Tags: php, mocking, redis, phpunit, predis

I'm trying to mock out the Predis client in a PHPUnit test. When I call the method I've tried to mock out, at the end of the test PHPUnit is telling me that the expectation was not met.

Here's a code sample that reproduces my problem:

```
class MockRedisTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
private $mockRedis;

public function testMockRedis() {

    $mockRedis =  $this->getMock('Predis\\Client');

    $mockRedis->expects(  $this->once())
      ->method("exists")
      ->with($this->equalTo("query-key"))
      ->will($this->returnValue(true));

    $mockRedis->exists("query-key");
}
```

}

And PHPUnit thinks the method wasn't called:

> 1) MockRedisTest::testMockRedis
>   Expectation failed for method name is equal to  when invoked 1 time(s).
>   Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.

Why?  Is it because the Predis client appears to be using __call to respond to method calls that match redis commands?

UPDATE: I get the impression it has something to do with the __call method.  Changing the code to this works:

```
public function testMockRedis() {

    $mockRedis =  $this->getMock('Predis\\Client');

    $mockRedis->expects(  $this->once())
      ->method("__call")
      ->with("exists", $this->equalTo(array("query-key")))
      ->will($this->returnValue(true));

    $mockRedis->exists("query-key");
}
```

Not sure I'm satisfied with this though.  Is there a better way to mock classes that use __call to proxy methods?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can use

```
$mockRedis =  $this->getMock('Predis\\Client', array('exists'));
// ...
```

to force the mock object to know about your magic function. This limits to mock's capabilities to the method `exists()` though. You'll have to specifically include every other method to be mocked.

Answer (score 1):

For Phpunit 5, use

```
$this->createPartialMock('Predis\\Client', ['exists']);
```

To make your mock know about the "exists" method (or any other redis native command)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mock a specific server profile and make sure you are not calling methods of a different server version, use

```php
<?php
$mockRedis = $this->getMock('Predis\\Client', array_keys((new Predis\Profiles\ServerVersion26)->getSupportedCommands()));
```