# PhpUnit mocking: function undefined

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I am writing some tests for my view helper. This is the first time I would like to do something with mocking objects. I'm using the default PHPUnit mocking Framework.

I have written a function which prepares my mock object:

```
private function getTestStub(){
    $mockResult = array();
    $mock =  $this->getMock('My\Entity\Product');
    $mock->expects($this->once())
                ->method('getId')
                ->will($this->returnValue(1));
    $mock->expects($this->once())
        ->method('getName')
        ->will($this->returnValue('jan'));
    $mock->expects($this->once())
        ->method('getWoonplaats')
        ->will($this->returnValue('Amsterdam'));
    $mockResult[] = $mock;
    return $mockResult;
}
```

Now when using this stub for my tests I get the following Error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mock_Product_129abca6::getId()
```

What Am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `Product::getId` exists? It's not a magic method (eg. something generated by `__call`)?

Comment: Well it's mocked as you can see in my code

Comment: You should post the class (or interfaced) defined at `My\Entity\Product`.

Comment: But that class is mocked. what has the real My\Entity\Product to do with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHPUnit looks at the class you're trying to mock via [reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) or [`get_class_methods`](http://www.php.net/get_class_methods).

The classes you mock, if they exist, are extended by the mock objects. Similarly interfaces are implemented. You can [see how this works](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects/blob/master/PHPUnit/Framework/MockObject/Generator.php#L851) in the code itself. It's bunch of code generation stuff, and if you want to take a look and trace how it works a good starting point is `PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Generator::generate`.

Without seeing your the class you're trying to mock, I'm going to guess that your getters are "magic" methods generated by `__call` with something like this:

```
<?php
namespace My\Entity;

class Product
{
    private $data = array();

    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        $set_or_get = strtolower(substr($method, 0, 3));
        $prop = strtolower(substr($method, 3));
        if ('get' === $set_or_get) {
            return isset($this->data[$prop]) ? $this->data[$prop] : null;
        } elseif ('set' === $set_or_get && isset($args[0])) {
            $this->data[$prop] = $args[0];
        } else {
            throw new \BadMethodCallException();
        }
    }
}
```

PHPUnit can't really do what you want because the methods you're trying to call don't actually exist and the magic `__call` doesn't work as expected. Either because PHPUnit uses that method itself something else (you'd have to dig in to find it). To get around this, you need to [tell PHPUnit which methods you want to include in your mock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6210784/1031898).

```
// the second argument let's you define methods
$mock =  $this->getMock('My\Entity\Product');
// try doing this instead
$mock =  $this->getMock('My\Entity\Product', array('getId', 'getName', 'getWoonplaats'));
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807368/why-isnt-my-phpunit-mock-of-the-predis-client-matching-my-expectations) also has some good examples of the above and workarounds.

Comment: Hmm i didn't understand from the PHPUnit manual that Mocking works like this. So If the mocket method does not exist in the actual class then it won't work and it will say that the method is undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped when I accidentally mocked 'foo\service\foobar` instead of `foo\entity\foobar`. Perhaps a TLDR could improve this answer: `method('foo')->willReturn('bar')` will not do anything if the class being mocked does not define that method.